# CORS SSE - Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: ruby, html, google-chrome, server-sent-events, goliath

I am developing a streaming server which send updates like latest tweets, news ets in realtime using [Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) and SSE. This server would be mapped to different domain.

**index.html**

```
<script>
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource('http://192.168.0.44:9000/api/stream/articles?channel=Headlines');

        // new connection opened callback
        source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
          console.log('connection opened');
        }, false);

        // new connection opened callback
        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
           msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
           $('#result').append('<br/>').append(msg);
        }, false);

        // connection closed callback
        source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
          if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            console.log('connection closed');
          }
        }, false);
    } else {
        $('#result').append('<br/>').append("Whoops! Your browser doesn't receive server-sent events.") ;
    }
  </script>
```

**Goliath component**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'goliath'

class RedisPubsub < Goliath::API
  use(Rack::Static, :root => Goliath::Application.app_path("public"), :urls => ["/index.html", "/twitter.html", "/favicon.ico", '/stylesheets/', '/javascripts/', '/images/'])
  use Goliath::Rack::Params
  use Goliath::Rack::Render, 'json'

  def response(env)
    ...
    ....
    env.stream_send("data:#{message}\n\n")
    streaming_response(200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'})
  end
end
```

The Goliath streaming server is running on 9000 port on local machine. When I try to access the page through `http://localhost/index.html` it give the error mentioned in Chrome even though it sends CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in response. Please not here it works fine on FF.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the Content-type header to text/event-stream as seen in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/.

Comment: Sorry I can't see that you already done that. Maybe you can try to send the header first.